# How to properly use a variable to scrollLeft within the animate function

Tags: javascript, scroll, syntax, jquery-animate

First, thanks in advance for any help.
Second, I would like to mention that I have looked at different questions related to this topic as well as read documentation for both animate() and scrollLeft() on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) I think my question is actually more based on syntax rather than function usage and that is why the other questions have not been as helpful to me.

Now, on to the issue. I am attempting to modify javascript code that I have previously written so that one function can react to the viewport of any user.

On the HTML side, I have a table with one `<tr>` and 3 `<td>`'s. The 3 `<td>`'s are filled with a picture and info and when the user clicks on buttons below, the table scrolls itself to the appropriate content. The buttons work fine. The problem is actually that the images are bigger than the viewport (on any device) and so on initial page load, the image needs to be scrolled by a distance proportional to both the viewport and the asset size (I load different assets based on viewport also). The formula for scroll distance, I discovered, is 
       `0.5( assetWidth ) - 0.5( viewportWidth )`.

So, here is the JS I have come up with (this is all inside a jQuery(document).ready(function($){

```
var scrollDistance;

if ($('#interactive-row:visible').length == 0) {
    //Viewport > 801px
    var assetWidth = 1920;
    console.log("bouta set scrolDistance");
    scrollDistance = ( 0.5 * assetWidth ) - ( 0.5 * $( window ).width() );
} else {
    //Viewport < 800px
    var assetWidth = 1428;
    scrollDistance = ( 0.5 * assetWidth ) - ( 0.5 * $( window ).width() );
}

//scroll to zero so that whne user goes "back" slider position is reset (w/o variable lastClick gets messed up)
$('.table-container').animate({
    scrollLeft: 0
}, "slow");
console.log( "Scroll Distance is " + scrollDistance + " calculation is about to begin." );
//move slider to middle of SSI screen
$('.table-container').animate({
    scrollLeft: += scrollDistance.valueOf() 
}, "slow");
```

The problem (I believe) is on the second-to-last line at which point my intentions are to have the browser scroll to whatever number is inside scrollDistance.

Note: here is what firefox and chrome say: "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '+='[Learn More]"

Also, I have already tried using scrollDistance with out adding the .valueOf(). I put that on recently in case there was some sort of type issue in javascript that I wasn't aware of.

Feel free to take a look at this graphic to better understand what I am trying to do. [Graphic of what browser should display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Pn4.png)

Thanks in advance for the help, I am new to Javascript and anything at all that you all can tell me (even just general pointers about how I write my code) is much appreciated!

Edit: It just occurred to me that it may also worth noting that my console.log() is not working at all but I could care less about that if the scroll starts working :D

Comment: `scrollLeft: += scrollDistance.valueOf()` is a syntax error: are you trying to create an object or increment scrollLeft?

Comment: I am trying to increment scrollLeft I believe. I want .table-container to be scrolled by the amount of pixels that are in the variable scrollDistance.

Comment: the colon shouldn't be there then

Comment: @user3080953 That did not solve the problem. That line of code now reads `$('.table-container').animate({
     scrollLeft += scrollDistance.valueOf() 
   }, "slow");`

Comment: shouldn't `valueOf` take an argument? why are you using "0" instead of 0 for scrollLeft? the error message in your question is no longer current, consider asking a new question

Comment: How is the error message in my question no longer current? I still have the same problem as I did when I created the question, so if my question is still unanswered, then opening a new question would only create two unanswered questions, right? Besides, the error message yielded from the console will, in some cases, mislead one from the root of the problem because error messages are not perfect (otherwise it would just tell me how to fix the problem and I would not have posted this question in the first place).

Comment: Now, as per valueOf(), according to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) `valueOf()` does not need (and I believe is not allowed to have) an argument.

Comment: The line of code with "0" is working already so it's likely that both "0" and 0 are accepted. But since you asked, the reason it is there (as my code comment in the original question explains) is to return the `.table-container` to the starting position (which is at "0") when a user clicks the back button on the browser or when the user refreshes the page. @user3080953

Comment: Your error message mentions a syntax error which was due to the extra colon: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '+='`. My mistake, you're right about `valueOf`. `"1" + 2 + 3` gives `123` whereas `1 + 2 + 3` gives `6`, which is why I was asking

Comment: Ah, I understand. So removing the quotes would be correct then, thank you!

Comment: Regarding the error message, I merely put that in to possibly assist with the solution of my question. I am under the assumption that the solution to this question will result in my code working. However, I am new to stack exchange, so I will do as you recommend: in this case do I need to create a new question? @user3080953

Comment: The reason I am hesitant to ask a new question is because my question is not how to fix the syntax, it is "How to properly use a variable to scrollLeft within the animate function." The syntax seems to be only one part of the larger problem.

Comment: Yup, you should ask a new question. I'd recommend a few things: create a minimal working demo as a stack snippet. If people can play with it, they'll be more likely to answer. Keep your question focused on one problem at a time so it has a clear question to answer. Finally, format it so it's easy to read. Feel free to @ mention me if you want me to take a look. Good luck!